# Retreiving JSON Data using PHP

Tags: php, json

```
$data = array (
'email' => 'ravi.uvi@yahoo.com',
'pwd' => 'success'
);

$bodyData = array (
'json' => json_encode($data)
);
```

THe above i have encoded the data in json.  And in my php file i decoded and stored that value to variable.  The result looks like this:

```
$result = {"email":"ravi.uvi@yahoo.com","pwd":"success"}
```

Now, i am trying to get the value of email and pwd using:

```
$emails = $result['email'];
$password = $result['pwd'];
```

I am not getting the values.  Please help me to get those values, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

use json_decode

```
$res = json_decode($result);
print_r($res);
```

Comment: :if i use $emails = $res['email']; i should get "ravi.uvi@yahoo.com" but its showing error repost as "Fatal Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: I got the output with your help.  I made a little change in the code which you suggested to me, such as $res = json_decode($result, true);  This one working fine.  Thanks a lot Prasanth.

Comment: If i have the decoded json data like this:
{"posts":{ "name":"ravi", "address":"chennai", "age":"24"; "gender":"male"}, { "name":"raghu", "address":"Trichy", "age":"26"; "gender":"male"}
How to get the values using foreach to get array value[0], and array value[1] etc...

Comment: print_r($res); see how the values are fetch each values based on that

Comment: you can use object notation for fetching values $res->posts